# PHP Mail Not Sending Messages

Tags: webserver, php

I realize this question title is pretty overused, but I couldn't find an answer to my problem. This could be because either I'm not too good with PHP and I don't understand the problem, or because I have a different issue, but I thought I would post it and see if somebody can help me.

I developed a website for a local church in my city and I made the site on my computer, put it onto my website as a sub directory and tested it all. It worked great. One of the things the client wanted was there to be an email form that can send emails. I made it and all was good.

I then uploaded it onto the church server and thought it went good too. But then we decided to try the email form out, and for some reason it didn't work.

I made the email form by having the user select a recipient (pastor, office manager, etc.) with a radio button, and that would change the action of the email form. I just did something like this:

```
if (recipent == "pastor") {
    document.forms[0].action = "../scripts/php/pastor_contact.php";
} else if (recipent == "pastoralAssist") {
    document.forms[0].action = "../scripts/php/pastoral_assist_contact.php";    
} else if (recipent == "famMinistry") {
    document.forms[0].action = "../scripts/php/sacra_assist_contact.php";   
} else if (recipent == "sacraAssist") {
    document.forms[0].action = "../scripts/php/fam_ministry_contact.php";   
}
```

I know this isn't the cleanest, but it works great. The php files then, all look very similar to this (just a different email)"

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone Number: $phone \n Message: $message";
$recipient = "email@example.com";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$mailheader = "$subject \r\n";
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("There seems to be an error with this form. Sorry about the inconveince. We are working to get this fixed.");
header('Location: ../../quickylinks/message_sent.html') ;
?>
```

What this does, briefly, is collect the information from the email form, submit it as an email and then redirect the user to a "Message Sent" page. This works on my server, but not theirs so I believe it's something to do with their server.

You can see their server information [here](http://holyfamilyregina.com/working.php) and mine [here](http://dejongdesign.ca/working.php).

When the user sends the message, they get "*There seems to be an error with this form. Sorry about the inconveince. We are working to get this fixed.*" and the email doesn't go through, although the code is the same on my server and it works fine there.

My initial thought was that PHP wasn't installed on their server (rare, but it does happen). But it was. So then I thought maybe it was installed, but the "mail" function was disabled. So I tried the following php code:

```
<?php 
if (function_exists('mail')) { 
    echo 'mail() is available'; 
} else { 
    echo 'mail() has been disabled'; }
?>
```

And it came back with "mail() is available".

So now I'm stuck and I don't know the problem could be.  As I said, I'm not very good at PHP yet so if somebody could give a detailed answer, I would be really really thankful!

Thank you so much!

Comment: `mail` returning `false` means that mailing is failing. Do you have a mail server/program actually installed on the remote server?

Comment: Try using `mail('you@email.com','some_subject','message_body')` and seeing if that works.  If it doesn't, your host may have mail disabled to prevent spamming.

Comment: @Waleed Khan, they've been using server for years. I know nothing about what they have installed on it.

Comment: @GigaWatt, I tried that and although I actually got to the "Message Sent" page, no message was sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server may not have mail program installed or configured properly.
To see into what is going on and fix the issue on clients server, you will need root access to it, and you may need to **ssh connect to their server to check / instal / configure what is neccessary**.

First thing you should maybe do is to login with ssh to their server (not applicable if it is just a shared host, probably), and try php cli interface, and try out stuff.

If nothing works, you will need to try editing **php.ini** file on their server to inform php what program it should use for mailing.

If that doesnt give you anything, you will need to install & configure **mail program**, cause it probably doesnt work right on their server.

**EDIT:**

At first sight, their server has **sendmail_path** with no value at all. It may mean that php has no clue thru which program it is supposed to send mail.

Your settings, however, show that you have **sendmail_path** setting   **/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i**

So edit **php.ini** file on their server, **sendmail_path** (you need to know the path of sendmail program on their server, obviously)

Comment: his production server is a Windows instalation

Comment: IT doesnt matter, you still need that setting / configuration.
Don't downvote it because the answer is valid regardless of their operating system.
Do you expect php to read your mind cause it's windows?

Comment: Reading my mind could be a nice thing(imagine the possibilities) but until then I expect most of Windows configurations not to have sendmail.exe and use something like an external SMTP, maybe something like Icewarp(phpinfo shows that it might be installed on the server) Anyway, I agree that down voting your answer was a little bit premature. My bad

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll be checking this out tomorrow. I think this may solve the issue! You rock!

Answer (score 0):

**Your production server is a Windows computer**

On the new server mail() is indeed available but is not configured.

In order to be able to send an email from php you need to edit php.ini to use a smtp server.

Your development server, a Linux server, is already configured properly. Your production server is a Windows computer that needs to be configured to send emails(edit the php.ini). By default Windows doesn't come with an built in email server so you will have to install one or use the one provided by your ISP.

Comment: You need to edit php.ini regardless of operating system. Why you downvote a valid response?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend you to use the [PHPMailer](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/downloads/detail?name=PHPMailer_5.2.2.tgz) class instead of the mail() function.

You can easily configure an smtp server (like the one of your client) and use it to send emails.

Look at the test_smtp_basic.php example for more information.

Answer (score -1):

From this `"You can see their server information here"` your server does not have sendmail path[image]

Comment: his production server is a Windows instalation